# macOS Terminal (or AppleScript) - Remove folder from Dock

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, macos-catalina

I have a folder on the right side of the Dock that I'd like to be able to remove via the command line (which I will ultimately add into an AppleScript script).

Is there a command line utility for removing a folder from the Dock?

Edit: I found this script, which removes a folder titled "Airdrop" from my dock by right-clicking on it, clicking `Options`, and then clicking `Remove from Dock`

```
tell application "System Events" to tell UI element "AirDrop" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
    perform action "AXShowMenu"
    click menu item "Options" of menu 1
    click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1 of menu item "Options" of menu 1
end tell
```

However, because it uses UI scripting, the rick-click menu appears as shown in the image below,  when the script is run.

Is there someway to prevent this menu from showing up on my screen when I run the script?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The script below can remove a named folder's dock tile from the dock.  Currently, it is set to remove the *Downloads* folder's dock tile, provided there is one.

```
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"

property this : a reference to the current application

property NSArray : a reference to NSArray of this
property NSMutableDictionary : a reference to NSMutableDictionary of this
property NSPredicate : a reference to NSPredicate of this
property NSPropertyList : a reference to NSPropertyListSerialization of this
property NSRunningApplication : a reference to NSRunningApplication of this
property NSString : a reference to NSString of this

property BinaryPList : 200

property id : "com.apple.dock"
property file : "~/Library/Preferences/" & id & ".plist"
property key : "persistent-others"
property keys : [key, "tile-data", "file-label", "lowercaseString"]


removeDockTileFolder("Downloads")
if the result = true then return killDock()
false


to removeDockTileFolder(directory as text)
    local directory

    set filepath to (NSString's ¬
        stringWithString:(my file))'s ¬
        stringByStandardizingPath()

    tell (NSMutableDictionary's dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath)
        tell valueForKeyPath_((NSArray's ¬
            arrayWithArray:(keys as list))'s ¬
            componentsJoinedByString:".")
            set N to |count|()
            set i to indexOfObject_((NSString's ¬
                stringWithString:directory)'s ¬
                lowercaseString())
            if i ≥ N then return false
        end tell

        valueForKey_(my key)'s removeObjectAtIndex:i

        tell (NSPropertyList's dataFromPropertyList:it ¬
            format:BinaryPList errorDescription:(missing value)) ¬
            to writeToFile:filepath atomically:yes
    end tell
end removeDockTileForFolder

to killDock()
    (runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier_(my id) ¬
        in the NSRunningApplication)'s terminate

    true
end killDock
```

Returns `true` upon success; `false` upon failure (the supplied name did not match the name of any of the folder dock tiles).

Comment: I just tried that and got the error `*** -[BAGenericObjectNoDeleteOSAID removeDockTileFolder]: unrecognized selector sent to object <BAGenericObjectNoDeleteOSAID @0x60000260f3a0: OSAID(1) ComponentInstance(0x810006)>` And, yes, I do have the donwloads folder in my dock @CJK

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's because the name of the handler is different to the handler being called.  Just change one to match the other, @PeterSchorn, ie. `removeDockTileForFolder` vs `removeDockTileFolder`.  I'll make the change in the post once you've seen this message.

Comment: While it no longer throws an error, it also is not working in that while it did remove the first target folder, it does not remove a different target folder when run a second time. The Dock was killed, but upon reappearing the target folder was still there.

Comment: It appears to work ok for me in successive runs (I have my MacBook running!). Are there any particular steps you can highlight to help me recreate the problem ? @user3439894

Comment: Looking at the contents of the target .plist file, the target data has been removed, but the target Dock Tile still exists and is active even though the killDock handler ran. Running `killall Dock` afterwards from Terminal removed the target Dock Tile, but that kind of defeats the purpose.  I was able to reproduce this two times after the initial working run, so I'm going to close everything and `purge` memory and see it I can replicate it again.

Comment: With that clue about the dock, I’ve made a small edit to the `killDock` handler: `"id" → "my id"`. I don’t yet know if that will affect what you’re experiencing, but it needed to be changed anyway.  `terminate` could be replaced with `forceTerminate`, to hard-quit the dock. I’m installing Catalina this week, and I’ll see how that changes things, although I don’t anticipate that being a cause as all of the methods used have been available for many versions.

Comment: Even with the current code and using forceTerminate I can replicate the issue. I will at some point reboot and test again just to confirm this solution is not working for me even though it may work for others (no pun as in persistent-others intended). I'll let you know when I do it but it may not be for a bit. That said, Peter Schorn has found [`dockutil`](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil), in another post he made, to handle his need.

Comment: After a reboot, nothing has changed, it works only once to remove the target Dock Tile the first run and then fails on subsequent runs with a different target Dock Tile, it does remove the data from the target .plist file but not the different target Dock Tile. `killall Dock` from Terminal after the fact removes the Dock Tile. Reboot, rinse and repeat. Sorry to say that as is, for me this is not a viable answer.

Comment: Thanks for testing @user3439894. Concluding it as nonviable is melodramatic: a very obvious fix is to insert the line `do shell script "killall Dock"`.  As I am still unable to reproduce this error and, for me, the script works seamlessly so far, I will dig deeper later in the week when I dive into Catalina. For now, you've nonetheless confirmed the script is doing what it is being told to do, so that's great. For code to do something once, but not twice, we both know infers something is amiss. If I can reproduce the problem but can't solve it, I'll withdraw the answer next weekend.

Comment: I said **as is** so no melodrama and I did try adding a `do shell script "killall Dock"` but again, **as is** _coded_ it would not compile if I did. (I didn't mention that to you, sorry) I would only withdraw the answer if other have the same issue or you can reproduce it with the _code_ **as is**. As to adding `do shell script "killall Dock"`, I removed the code for killDock() and its _handler_ and added `do shell script "killall Dock"` after `removeDockTileFolder("Downloads")` and got: **Syntax Error** Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier. -- I just don't have any more time for it

Comment: @user3439894 No, I don't expect you to invest yourself too much into this.  It's amazing that you've done as much as you have, I'm very grateful.  The error you mentioned (just so you know if it arises in your projects) is because the script **as is** doesn't have a `use scripting additions` line at the top.  Currently, **as is**, it doesn't require it, but if it wishes to utilise any _scripting additions_ commands, it is required by any script that imports anything else with the `use` statement, because AppleScript reasons.

Comment: Copying the _code_, as currently is, from the answer to **Script Editor** it compiles fine, however then adding `use scripting additions` returns "**Syntax Error** Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found “:”." on the last `:` in this segment of _code_: `tell (NSPropertyList's dataFromPropertyList:it ¬ format:BinaryPList`